# Wrong Navigation Bar as a result of swipe back

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three view controllers: `HomeViewController`,`FooViewController`, `FooDetailViewController`.

First two view controllers have navigation bars whereas last one does not, but last one does have a back button and when pressed, it goes back to `FooViewController`.

Bug occurs in following sequence of steps:

1) User follows the path: `HomeViewController`,`FooViewController`, `FooDetailViewController`

2) User starts to swipe back from `FooDetailViewController` but gives up. Finally, to note, User is now in `FooDetailViewController`.

3) User follows the path: `FooDetailViewController`, `FooViewController`, `HomeViewController`

Bug part: Navigation bar of `HomeViewController` is exactly same as `FooViewController`, that should not occur though.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you pls be more specific in your question? Provide some code, screenshots, etc.